# Place an absolute-positioned element behind an relative-positioned element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to place the absolute-positioned `#element` behind the relative-positioned `#container` ID, if the former is a child of the latter ?

In other words, how can I get the red element to be positioned **between** the blue element and the yellow element??

`z-index` doesn't seem to work.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9godfn1/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="big_container">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#big_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
#container, #element {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    background:blue;
}

#element {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:red;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

**Updated**.

Comment: well first of all, if you want the blue item on top, the z-index should be higher than the red element

Answer (score 4):

Remove thew `z-index` from the parent and set the child to `-1`

```css
#container, #element {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
}
#element {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background:red;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that code will hide #element completely and place it behind ALL other containers, and I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Please update your question and specify your exact requirements

Answer (score 1):

just apply **z-index : -1** to the **red** block and remove the position property  of **blue** block it will work

```css
#container, #element ,#element1 ,#element2 {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
#container {
      z-index: 5;
    background: #00F;
}
#element {
       position: absolute;
    z-index: -8;
    background: #F00;
    top: 21px;
    left: 5px;
}
#element1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9;
    background: #008000;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}
#element2 {
     position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
    background: #FF0;
    top: 27px;
    left: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="element"></div>
     <div id="element1"></div>
     <div id="element2"></div>
</div>
```

here you can check out you can manage those divs with minus z-indexing
here is the demo example

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4oyau3wy/4/)

Comment: @Daniel Sarmas you can check out this

Comment: i have small doubt why parent container is not taking z-index even if i make it position relative as static position wont work with z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pseudo element` in css, if it's *just about drawing*... :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/4oyau3wy/1/

**Css**:

```
#container, #element {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
#container:before {
    content:"";
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:5;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
}
#element:before {
    content:"";
    width: 50px;
        height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:4;
    background:red;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```